# php array with session

Tags: php, session

So pretty easy, the code changes the images on page reload, it works, though I get undeifned index bg, error. tried to fix it, the error goes away but the code doesnt work, note that I have another session with another name started in the page where the below code outputs its result.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['bg'])){
        $bg = array ('../sky.jpg', '../sky2.jpg', '../sky3.jpg');
        $i = ++$_SESSION['bg'] % count($bg);
        $_SESSION['bg'] = $i;
        $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";

?>
```

Comment: why dont you just generate an random number with mt_rand(0, count($bg) - 1) and use the random number as key for your $bg array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't initialising the session variable. The isset will only work if the variable exists.

Try changing your code to:

```
<?php

    $bg = array ('../sky.jpg', '../sky2.jpg', '../sky3.jpg');

    if(isset($_SESSION['bg'])){
        $i = ++$_SESSION['bg'] % count($bg);
    } else {
        $i = 0;
    }

    $_SESSION['bg'] = $i;
    $selectedBg = $bg[$i];

?>
```

This way you are checking to see if the session variable is set and assigning the value accordingly. If it is not set you are assigning a default value.

**Random Number Solution**

As per MacGyer's comment on your question, you could assign a random number between 0 and array length. The following code will generate that:

```
  <?php

        $bg = array ('../sky.jpg', '../sky2.jpg', '../sky3.jpg');

        $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);

        $selectedBg = $bg[$i];

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add this top of page.

```
session_start();
```

Full version;

```
<?php
session_start();
$bg = array('../sky.jpg', '../sky2.jpg', '../sky3.jpg');

if(isset($_SESSION['bg'])){
    $i = ++$_SESSION['bg'] % count($bg);
    $_SESSION['bg'] = $i;
    $selectedBg = $bg[$i];
} else {
    $_SESSION['bg'] = 0;
    $selectedBg = $bg[0]; 
}
```